# Excel dates table intersection with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have one excel page and I store date type datas. This datas extra workdays and plus holidays in every year. Other table in this page has start and end date. I would like to show some interval the employees work days. I would like to use the VBA. How to solved this problem?

Comment: Can you post sample data, expected outcome and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite NETWORKDAYS.INTL?

Answer (score 1):

Use [NETWORKDAYS.INTL()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28)

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E2,F2,1,A2:A3)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This pictures the Excel table and my code:

```
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim retValue As Integer
Dim days As Variant
Dim dates As Variant


days = Worksheets("Tényleges munkanapok").ListObjects("TáblázatKorrekciósNapok").DataBodyRange.Value
dates = Worksheets("Tényleges munkanapok").ListObjects("TáblázatSzámoló").DataBodyRange.Value


Dim i As Integer
Dim actualDate As Date

startDate = days(1, 1)
actualDate = dates(1, 1)



Dim CountVariant As Integer
CountVariant = UBound(days)
i = 0

Do While i <= CountVariant
    If startDate < actualDate Then
    i = i + 1
End If    
Loop
```

Comment: Unless this actually answers your question, please edit your original post with this update and do not use the Answer or Comment space for clarification updates.  If this answers the question then please explain better why it answered the question.